# How to add a resource file in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resx, resource-files

I want to add a resource file to my project in `Visual Studio`. But I am not able to find from where I can create the `resource file`. Can anyone help me out in this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Right click on Solution` **>** `Add New Item` **>** `Visual C#` **>** `General` **>** `Select Resources File (Resource1.resx)`

As per ShooShoSha: You need to have one of the "Windows workloads" installed in "Visual Studio Installer" for the "Resource File" to be available.

[image: Add New Item dialog]

Comment: I tried the same thing but i am not able to find the resource file

Comment: @appu What is version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: microsoft visual studio premium 2012    version:11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Comment: @appu Can you add screenshot of add new item screen here?

Comment: @appu I've added image in my answer.

Comment: If you are using a later version, Visual Studio may use the "Visual Studio Installer". When installing VS this way, the available template files depend on the workloads you choose to install. For a resources file template, you will need to include one of the Windows workloads for it to be available.

Comment: @appu add to project, not solution